# I'm not able to access my Async Validator as it comes in "__zone_symbol" object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I have made this async validator

```
export class PasswordsValidators{
    static oldPasswordMatch(control: AbstractControl) : Promise<ValidationErrors> | null {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if(control.value !== "1234")
                resolve({oldPasswordInvalid:true})
            else
                resolve(null); 
        });
    }
}
```

But not able to get `oldPasswordInvalid` variable because it comes inside some object `__zone_symbol__value` like this.

[image]

This is the formGroup

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    oldPassword: new FormControl("",[
      Validators.required,
      PasswordsValidators.oldPasswordMatch
    ]),
    newPassword: new FormControl("",[
      Validators.required      
    ]),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl("",[
      Validators.required      
    ])
  })
```

This is the front-end

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Old Password</label>
    <input 
    formControlName="oldPassword"
    type="password" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Password">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="oldPassword.invalid && oldPassword.touched">
      <p *ngIf="oldPassword.errors.required"> Should be filled </p>
      <p *ngIf="oldPassword.errors.oldPasswordInvalid">Didn't match</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Can somebody explain, What's I'm missing here ?

Comment: Hi .. mybe it's not right .. but i think you've missed somthing in the input .. to pass the VALUE of the textbox to the validation .. so it can't get the value and throw an error (cause it's marked as required) .. maybe try to put a [ngValue] or [ngModel] in your input ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing your async validators along with with sync ones. Here's the solution:

```
form = new FormGroup({
    oldPassword: new FormControl("",
      [Validators.required],
      [PasswordsValidators.oldPasswordMatch] // note that async validators are passed as the third parameter
    ),
    newPassword: new FormControl("",[
      Validators.required      
    ]),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl("",[
      Validators.required      
    ])
  })
```

Comment: Hey thanks, It worked. One thing though. It doesn't work the first time. Once you take the focus off it works. [Like this](https://imgur.com/a/VQLrl)

Comment: Yeah, that's the expected behavior of Angular validators. Glad it helped.